# Update all outdated Angular packages at once

Tags: angular, bash, grep, angular-cli

I've previously used `ng update --all`, cause I want to update every package to the latest version, including those dependencies which do not have schematics attached to it.

The `--all` option is now deprecated and will not function any more. The only option is to specify each package to update and I find that tedious. Is there a way to grep the outdated package output from `ng update` into a single line space separated variable which can then be input to a new `ng update ${packageList}`?

The output from `ng update` is as follows:

```
The installed local Angular CLI version is older than the latest stable version.
Installing a temporary version to perform the update.
Installing packages for tooling via npm.
Installed packages for tooling via npm.
Using package manager: 'npm'
Collecting installed dependencies...
Found 67 dependencies.
    We analyzed your package.json, there are some packages to update:

      Name                                     Version                  Command to update
     --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      @angular/cdk                             10.2.5 -> 11.0.0         ng update @angular/cdk
      @angular/cli                             10.1.7 -> 11.0.0         ng update @angular/cli
      @angular/core                            10.2.0 -> 11.0.0         ng update @angular/core
      @angular/material                        10.2.5 -> 11.0.0         ng update @angular/material
      @nrwl/angular                            10.3.1 -> 10.3.3         ng update @nrwl/angular
      @nrwl/cypress                            10.3.1 -> 10.3.3         ng update @nrwl/cypress
      @nrwl/jest                               10.3.1 -> 10.3.3         ng update @nrwl/jest
      @nrwl/storybook                          10.3.1 -> 10.3.3         ng update @nrwl/storybook
      @nrwl/workspace                          10.3.1 -> 10.3.3         ng update @nrwl/workspace

    There might be additional packages which don't provide 'ng update' capabilities that are outdated.
    You can update the addition packages by running the update command of your package manager.
```

I want to run a bash script which collects only the package names from the first column of this output, and feeds it back into a variable. The end result being:

```
> ng update ${packageList}

ng update @angular/cdk @angular/cli @angular/core @angular/material @nrwl/angular @nrwl/cypress @nrwl/jest @nrwl/storybook @nrwl/workspace --force=true
```

Help? Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Think I got it with this one-liner:

```sh
ng update | awk -v re='@[[:alnum:]]' '$0 ~ re {printf $1 " "}' | xargs ng update --force=true && npm update
```

By piping the output of the first `ng update` run into awk, I can search for text which resembles package names and output a space-separated list of arguments which I then pipe as xargs into a second `ng update` command.

By running this first and `npm update` after, I get every single dependency with migration schematics updated firstly, then all the rest afterwards. Happy!

Comment: The solution does not work after upgrading to version 13.

Answer (score 0):

DISCLAIMER: BACKUP YOUR ENTIRE PROJECT FIRST BEFORE RUNNING THIS COMMAND.

```
ng update @angular/cli @angular/core --force --allow-dirty
```

Comment: This will NOT update every dependency in package.json. Only @angular/cli and @angular/core.

Comment: @ØysteinAmundsen, Thanks sweet potato, but I think the question was about "angular" packages, not all in package.json. :)

Comment: Still, this will only update two of them.

Comment: -No, this will update ALL the angular packages, like @angular/*

Answer (score 0):

try this command
ng update --legacy-peer-deps

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
npm update --save-dev
```